# Primary SSD on Dell Precision 7510 Cannot Be Detected by Ubuntu Installer

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I've been trying to install Ubuntu along with the pre-installed Win 10 on my new Dell Precision 7510 with a PCIe SSD as the primary hard drive (this is where Win 10 was pre-installed) and a SATA HDD as the second hard drive. The problem is that Ubuntu installer cannot detect the SSD. It can only recognize my HDD and the USB thumb drive that I used for installation. The fdisk command doesn't list the SSD either. I've tried both 14.04 and 15.10 and neither worked. However there is no issue with the SSD when running Windows. Anyone's got the same issue or knows how to fix it? I'm pretty new to Linux so any advice would be a big help. Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the boot option "nvme_load=YES". http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307273&p=13416829#post13416829 AND: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN151664/en  AND is UEFI/BIOS most current version from Dell?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to install both Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10 on the Dell Precision 7510 (settled for Ubuntu 15.10 due to out-of-the-box Wireless driver support).
In order for the installer to recognise the disk I went into the BIOS:

System Configuration -> SATA Operation -> Choose AHCI

Apply and Exit

That did the trick for me.

Comment: This saved [my data's life](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075527/110181). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable SATA-0 as well. Ubuntu did not install right away. SSD card was not recignized in 14.04. Installed openSuse first, than Ubuntu install worked fine

Answer (score 0):

on my Dell Precision T5600 SSD was not getting detected by windows 10 setup . After spending hours, it turns out that there are SATA ports separate then HD ports although they have same connector . once I plug-in SSD in one of the ports marked as SATA (partially covered by a cover) it start working as expected.