# Booting problem - local-block gave up (NVME on Dell XPS 15 2017)

Tags: 16.04, dell, disk, boot-repair

I had a spill over the keyboard of a Dell XPS 15 (9560; 2017 model) yesterday. The laptop had some issues booting due to critical temperature. After solving this issue and getting the laptop back booting up normally I faced the problem with the NVME disk onboard.

I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed and running. The only Windows part on the disk is the Windows repair partition*.

I can see the NVME disk in the bios (see 1st picture below) and running Dell diagnostics passes the tests with no problems.

I booted into the Windows repair and it boots fine. However the installed Ubuntu complains about it. See 2nd picture below.

On a live USB disk:

- nvme is not detected and no partitions are shown
- `lspci` & `lshw` get stuck. Might be a problem with the circuits?

Using GRUB's command line I was able to see thepartitions and their UUIDs a well as their sizes. I can see the corresponding root, home, and data partitions. Is this list saved in Grub or reflects the physical disk?

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

PS 1: I did not touch the disk during repair.

PS 2: Disk is encrypted.

*The Windows 10 OS was removed before installing Ubuntu a year ago. However I kept the Windows repair partition.

[image]
[image]

**Update 1**: When I installed Ubuntu I didn't change the system configuration from RAID0 TO AHCI as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/719460) . Doing this allowed me to boot up and log in and to start backuping up.

**Update 2**: During the back up process the laptop turned off and I wasn't able to  boot again. It is actually not turning on.

Comment: What did you spill? A laptop Toshiba dropped in a lake, frozen and un-thawed worked ok after drying out. Not suggesting you rinse everything with water and dry thoroughly if you spilled coffee or pop on the keyboard but...

Comment: It was scotch, abut half a glass.  I assumed this w as not as harmful as water given that it would evaporate quicker than water. Also, I did open the laptop the second day after drying and cleaned its fans while checking for any potential damage. Also note I got a message of critical temperature several times.

Comment: I think the sugar in scotch will make it more damaging. Hence rinsing with water would be preferable. But this is not professional advise... One other point, after the Toshiba Laptop was unthawed and dried out. It still wouldn't boot past BIOS until the battery was taken out.

Comment: I did unplug the battery multiple times during the multiple times I opened the laptop up.