# Rescue data from NVMe using external encolsure?

Tags: 16.04, backup, data-recovery, nvme

As per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075527/booting-problem-local-block-gave-up-nvme-on-dell-xps-15-2017/1075736), would it work to put the NVMe disk into an external enclosure and extract the data from the encrypted data and /home partitions on an 8-year old laptop wih USB 2?